# Commandline video/image crossfading

Tags: image, video, command-line, ffmpeg, mencoder

I have a `test.avi`
using `ffmpeg` or `mencoder` or some other commandline utility,
I want to take `splash.png` put it at the beginning of the video,
fade it out, show test.avi, then at the end of test.avi, fade splash.png back in.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4):

I would try to convert the image to a video [-f image2](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#image2-2) and after I would use the [fade-in/out effect](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#fade)